# Creating instances of Abstract Data Types that recursively contain each other

Tags: data-structures, haskell, recursion, abstract-data-type

Given two date types defined as follows:

```
data Foo = Foo Bar String
data Bar = Bar Foo String
```

How can I make `foo` and `bar` such that `foo` is `Foo bar "foo"` and `bar` is `Bar foo "bar"`?

What about when we change the types to:

```
data Foo = Foo Bar (MVar String)
data Bar = Bar Foo (MVar String)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using a `let` is enough (`let` in Haskell is `letrec`, and supports mutually recursive definitions). The mutually recursive definitions set up cycles in the heap, that look like this:

[image: foo bar let rec]

The `MVar` initialization doesn't really change things in any meaningful way.

```
import Control.Concurrent

data Foo = Foo Bar (MVar String)

data Bar = Bar Foo (MVar String)

main = do
    a <- newMVar "foo"
    b <- newMVar "bar"

    let foo = Foo bar a
        bar = Bar foo b

    return ()
```

Comment: but the `MVar`s have to be created outside of the `let` statement?

Comment: That's right. They must be initialized in the IO monad, first. And there's no need here for mutual monadic recursion.

Answer (score 5):

Don answered the question as asked, but a slightly more interesting question is how to deal with

```
data Foo = Foo (MVar Bar) String
data Bar = Bar (MVar Foo) String
```

Now the two MVars aren't mere bystanders to the recursion, they are accomplices.

This can be done two ways:

1.) Either by doing what you would do in an imperative language like C:

```
mutation = do
   -- setting up an empty mvar
   bar <- newEmptyMVar
   foo <- newMVar (Foo bar "foo")
   -- and then filling it in
   putMVar bar (Bar foo "foo")
   return (foo, bar)
```

2.) or by using DoRec (formerly RecursiveDo) and `mfix` and behind the scenes tie the knot:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DoRec #-} 

mutual = do
   rec foo <- newMVar (Foo bar "foo")
       bar <- newMVar (Bar foo "foo")
   return (foo, bar)
```

This translates to something analogous to:

```
mutual = do
   (foo, bar) <- mfix $ \(foo, bar) -> do
       foo <- newMVar (Foo bar "foo")
       bar <- newMVar (Bar foo "foo")
       return (foo, bar)
  return (foo, bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine thanks to Haskells lazyness.

```
data Foo = Foo Bar String deriving Show
data Bar = Bar Foo String deriving Show

test = let
  foo = Foo bar "foo"
  bar = Bar foo "bar"
  in foo
```